# is there a way on how to copy Temporary Internet Files?

Tags: delphi, caching, filesystems, temporary-files, special-folders

help me how to copy file from Temporary Internet Files on xp or higher. copyfile not is working on it.

i want to make it like `CopyFileEx(scr, dst):boolean`

Comment: _is not working on it_ is not as good to wonder what is happening there.. consider adding the exact error message/exception you're getting and don't forget to include information about how you're copying the file (maybe a bit of code)

Comment: Is it your temporary internet files, or a version owned by another user? I'm sure Windows protects users from reading other users internet cache.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using wrong path. this folder [**Internet temporary files**] has especial structure, to see this structure, try to search it with [**faAnyFile**] attribute like this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  path: Array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  sRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE, 0,0, @path);
  if FindFirst(PATH+'\*.*', faAnyFile, sRec) = 0 then
    Begin
      repeat
        ListBox1.Items.Add(sRec.Name);
      until (FindNext(sRec) <> 0);
      FindClose(sRec);
    End;
end;
```

You will find some folders there like (Content.IE5, Content.MSO, AntiPhishing… ), under folder Content.IE5 you can also  find sub-folders with random names like this:

```
<path>temporary internet files\content.ie5\randomfoldername
```

So,if you are looking for the cash files you can find it in these random sub-folders but you have to write search algorithm to search these folders for the file you want, and then you can copy it using its real path.

EDIT:
also you can see the real structure of the [**Internet temporary files**] directory using the **dir** command from dos CMD like this:
[image]

BTW: don't forget to use th Short Path Name in Dos.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with IE's cache is to use the WinInet API for that, in this case the `GetUrlCacheEntryInfo/Ex()` functions.  Pass in the original URL, and it will return the exact local path to the cached file (amongst other things), which you can then copy as needed.  Also have a look at the `FindFirst/NextUrlCache...()` functions for enumerating the contents of the cache.